# Number of ring homomorphisms from a finite field to its extension

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields, extension-field

I am trying to prove the following statement stated in the proof of another theorem:

> Given the finite field extensions $\mathbb{F}_p\subset
> \mathbb{F}_{p^d} \subset \mathbb{F}_{p^n}$, there are $d$ ring
>   homomorphisms $\mathbb{F}_{p^d}\to \mathbb{F}_{p^n}$.

The closest result I could find on StackExchange is the following:

*Let $\mathbb{Q}$ $\subset$ $K$ $\subset$ $\mathbb{C}$ with $[K:\mathbb{Q}]$ finite. Then the number of field homomorphisms from $K$ to $\mathbb{C}$ is equal to $[K: \mathbb{Q}]$. [[Proof]](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/180088/214604)*

**My attempt:**

Since the exensions over prime subfield are simple, $\mathbb{F}_{p^d} = \mathbb{F}_p(\alpha)$ and $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}=\mathbb{F}_p(\beta)$ for some $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$. Then the $d$ homomorphisms are given by identity map and $\alpha^j\mapsto \beta$ for $1\leq j\leq d-1$. Existence of any other map should contradict the injective property of homomorphism, but how? I am not sure whether my argument makes sense.

Comment: Of course you have to assume $d\mid n$.

Comment: @egreg Yes, it's there since $\mathbb{F}_{p^d}$ is a subfield of $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$.

Comment: I suppose that a ring homomorphism is unital by definition, otherwise there'd be one more.  Note that a ring homomorphism $\mathbb{F}_{p^d} \to \mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ is in fact an automorphism of $\mathbb{F}_{p^d}$. Then consider Frobenius.

Comment: Use the Galois correspondence, because finite fields are Galois over their subfields. What's the Galois group of $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$?

Comment: @egreg $\text{Gal}(\mathbb{F}_{p^n}/\mathbb{F}_p)=\langle \sigma_p\rangle \cong \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ where $\sigma_p$ is Frobenius automorphism.

Comment: @DanielFischer Since the extension is Galois, $|\text{Aut}(\mathbb{F}_{p^d}/\mathbb{F}_p)|=[\mathbb{F}_{p^d}:\mathbb{F}_p]=d$. But why is this homomorphism an automorphism?

Comment: The image is a subfield of $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ of order $p^d$.