# Number of ring homomorphisms from a finite field to its finite extension

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields

Let $k$ be a field with 8 elements and $K$ a field with 64 elements. How many ring homomorphisms are there from $k$ to $K$?

This question was asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2812738/number-of-ring-homomorphisms-from-a-finite-field-to-its-extension) but it has no proper answers. As much as I have understood any field homomorphism from $k$ to $K$ will be a $k$-automorphism that fixes $\mathbb{F}_2$. Also, any finite extension of a finite field is Galois. Hence, the number of homomorphisms equals $|Gal(k/\mathbb{F}_2)|$ i.e., $3$.

Comment: Yes, these were the (seemingly sufficient) comments of that post. So, what is your question?

Comment: I wasn't sure about it. I have been self-learning these things. Thank you by the way.